# What would be a robust way to read in multiple floats from stdin in c? (unknown number of elements, unknown format))

Tags: c, floating-point, stdin

I have recently ran into the need to read in multiple floats from  stdin in a wide range of scenarios.  So far most of what i have been using is scanf() but am wondering if there is a generic/robust way to handle this in C.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by wide range of scenarios? can you be more specific.

Comment: Floats arranged in a single column,or multiple columns.  Separated by commas, or spaces ect.  5 elements or 1000.

Comment: `while (scanf("%*f") == 1)` will "read in multiple floats from stdin".  Likely you want more than this, but then the post does not specify what or how to save them.  Suggest expanding your post by posting an example fo your goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily read as many `floats` as you like from `stdin` by calling `strtof` in a loop. One approach to this is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {

    char *line = NULL;      /* buffer to hold input on stdin    */
    char *sp = NULL;        /* start pointer for parsing line   */
    char *ep = NULL;        /* end pointer for parsing line     */
    int cnt = 0;            /* simple counter for floats        */
    float flt = 0.0;        /* variable to hold float           */

    printf ("\n enter any number of floats you like as input ([enter] without number to quit)\n");
    while (printf ("\n input: ") && scanf ("%m[^\n]%*c", &line) >= 1)
    {
        cnt = 0;
        sp = line;
        while (*sp)
        {
            flt = strtof (sp, &ep);                         /* convert value to float           */
            if (sp != ep) {                                 /* test that strtof processed chars */
                sp = ep;                                    /* set sp to ep for next value      */
                printf ("  float [%d]  %f\n", cnt+1, flt);  /* output the float value read      */
                cnt++;                                      /* increase float count             */
            } else {
                break;
            }
            sp++;                                           /* skip space or comma separator    */

        }
    }

    if (line) free (line);                                  /* free memory allocated by scanf   */

    return 0;
}
```

**input/output:**

```
$ ./bin/floatread

 enter any number of floats you like as input ([enter] without number to quit)

 input: 2.3 4.5 6.7, 8.1
  float [1]  2.300000
  float [2]  4.500000
  float [3]  6.700000
  float [4]  8.100000

 input: 21.3.45.6,81.2,99.3 29.8
  float [1]  21.299999
  float [2]  45.599998
  float [3]  81.199997
  float [4]  99.300003
  float [5]  29.799999

 input:
```